# cannot update field of a model in odoo 14

Tags: python, api, odoo-14

i need a help, what i want to do is to create a method for action button to fetch data from other application api and then update a field in my odoo model with fetched data. this is my code

```html
from odoo import api, fields, models, exceptions
import requests

class MySuperhero(models.Model):
    _name = "my.superhero"

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    description = fields.Text()
    
    def action_djbc_process(self):
    
      myname = self.name
      url = "https://superhero-search.p.rapidapi.com/api/"
      querystring = "{'hero':'" + myname + "'}"

      headers = {
                  'x-rapidapi-host': "superhero-search.p.rapidapi.com",
                  'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                  }
       response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring )
       time.sleep(3)
                            
       hero = response.json().get('name')
       intelligence = response.json().get('powerstats').get('intelligence')

       self.description = hero + " " + str(intelligence)               
                    
       return True
```

but why get same fetched data and not updated the field, but if i fetch data using curl, the fetched data can change based on querystring ?

Comment: Hi joko, can you please elaborate on what's your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.